# Using angularjs variable inside iframe

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe

So I want to use a variable inside a iframe src or ng-src attribute. 
Apparently none of my variables get ever recognized, whatever I use. 
For example `

```
<iframe ng-src="http://www.example.com/?name={{test}}">
</iframe>
```

where test just get displayed as `{{test}}` ....

Also when I use `$sce` to use it as a trusted url it doesn't work, same goes for normal src..

Is there something I don't see? Is there something about Iframes and angularjs?
Please share, its really annoying.

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,
In your controller do -
replace the `ng-src="{{test}}"` -- use a variable for the whole url.
and then -

```
$scope.test=$sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.example.com");
```

also include $sce in your controller dependency.

It worked for me..
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the src property with this syntax:

> iframeObject.src = URL

**To note**: *URL* specifies the URL of the content to embed and it can be
   either an absolute or a relative URL.

Example:

```js
document.getElementById('embedContent').src = "http://www.example.com";
```

```css
#embedContent{
        width: 600px;
        height: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<iframe id="embedContent" src="#"></iframe>
```

Because you also want to concatenate / merge two strings, you can just change the JavaScript to

```
document.getElementById('embedContent').src = "http://www.example.com/?name=" + test;
```